# Can the monero-wallet-rpc handle multiple requests at the same time?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

For example, to process several "transfer" requests in parallel. The question is about [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp) implementation of the wallet. I can't figure it out quickly on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wallet RPC server is not really designed for high traffic, concurrent connections. It only operates on one wallet at a time and runs single threaded. I.e. it assumes only one person is using it at a time, so only one call needs handling each time.

Very near the top of the linked file ([line 144](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fd3ff741644152ed559fcf79550435d3df75b764/src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp#L144)), you can see:

```
//DO NOT START THIS SERVER IN MORE THEN 1 THREADS WITHOUT REFACTORING
return epee::http_server_impl_base<wallet_rpc_server, connection_context>::run(1, true);
```

Which points out this is running in a single thread.

This of course does not prevent multi-user, multi-wallet setups, it just means you would need to run multiple *processes* of the `monero-wallet-rpc`.